# What does "points spanned by powers" mean in the Goffinet dragon definition?

Tags: definition, fractals

The **[definition of the Goffinet dragon fractal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoffinetDragon.html)** given by Wolfram Mathworld refers to

> plotting all points spanned by powers of the complex number p=0.65-0.3i

What does it mean for points to be "spanned by powers"?

---

I initially guessed that this simply meant that all the successive integer powers of p should be plotted. However, plotting $p$, $p^2$, $p^3$ simply gives a spiral heading towards zero, and not the fractal image displayed on the Wolfram page.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this book](https://books.google.it/books?id=9DGhukeFNLIC&lpg=PP1&dq=The%20Mathematica%20GuideBook%20for%20Graphics&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is referenced in the definition you linked to, you'll see that the points in the Goffinet dragon are all the points of the form
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k p^k
$$
with $a_k$ either $0$ or $1$. Of course, for practical purposes the points actually plotted in a picture need to be cut off at some fixed power.

Comment: This makes sense now - thank you. I had tried to view the relevant pages before asking the question, but they were not included in the preview I was using. The one you link to gives the full explanation and a recursive approach to plotting.

Comment: @trichoplax Put another way - it's the set of all linear combinations of the numbers $p^k$ where the coefficients can be either zero or one. If you consider that these coefficients form a [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), then this is exactly the linear the span of the $p^k$s.